# fetching of json from url is stuck

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, fetch

Trying to fetch some json from the following url: https://talaikis.com/api/quotes/random/

I'm using an activity indicator while waiting for the json to be fetched. That apparently never happens and so the app just displays the activity indicator. I tried using the sample that is provided in the [networking tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network) in the official react native documentation

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import Header from '../header/Header';

export default class SingleQuote extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    isLoading: true
  }
}

loadingQuoteFromUrl(){
  return fetch('https://talaikis.com/api/quotes/random/')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {

    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: responseJson,
    }, function(){

    });

  })
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.error(error);
 });
}

render() {
  var style = require("./styles.js");

  if(this.state.isLoading){
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
        <ActivityIndicator/>
      </View>
    )
  }    

  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <Header text="Daily Quote" />

      <View style={style.textContainer}>
        <Text
          adjustsFontSizeToFit 
          numberOfLines={3}
          style={style.textStyle}
        > 
          {this.state.dataSource.quote} 
        </Text>

        <Text
          adjustsFontSizeToFit
          numberOfLines={1}
          style={style.textStyle}
        >
          {this.state.dataSource.author}
        </Text>

      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

}

Comment: don't seem to call `loadingQuoteFromUrl()` anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not invoking `loadingQuoteFromUrl` anywhere in your App. For fetch operations `componentDidMount` is a suitable lifecycle method. So, you can use it. But first, you should bind this function in order to use `this` context. You can do this in the constructor or define it as an arrow function without binding.

```js
class SingleQuote extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    };
    this.loadingQuoteFromUrl = this.loadingQuoteFromUrl.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadingQuoteFromUrl();
  }

  loadingQuoteFromUrl() {
    return fetch("https://talaikis.com/api/quotes/random/")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson
          },
          function() {}
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.dataSource.quote}</p>

          <p>{this.state.dataSource.author}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SingleQuote />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This looks good. May also want to set `isLoading:` to `false` in the `catch` block.

Comment: @AaronBrager, thanks. I haven't touched that side of the code. But, doing what you said is so logical since OP does not want to see the loading part forever if there is a problem in fetching :) Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SingleQuote extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadingQuoteFromUrl();
  }

  loadingQuoteFromUrl = () => {
    return fetch("https://talaikis.com/api/quotes/random/")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson
          },
          function() {}
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState(
        {
          isLoading: false,
        }
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;
    const { dataSource } = this.props;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>{dataSource.quote}</p>
          <p>{dataSource.author}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SingleQuote />, document.getElementById("root"));
```